# Displaying Page title from database getting error as Array to string converstion in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am trying to fetch page title dynamically for all the pages from database.But Getting the error as

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity:Notice</p>
<p>Message: Array to string Converstion</p>
<p>FileName:templates/header.php</p>
```

Controller:

```
function index()
{     

    $data['page_title']=$this->testimonial_model->getpagetitle($this->uri->segment(1));
    $data['mainpage'] = "testimonial";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function getpagetitle($id)
{
    $this->db->select('P.*,T.testimonial_name');        
    $this->db->from('pagetitle AS P');
    $this->db->join('testimonials AS T','T.testimonial_name=P.page_title','INNER');     
    $q=$this->db->get();    
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    return $q->result();
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Templates/header.php

```
<?php if(!empty($page_title)){?>
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
<?php }else{ ?>
<title>Solutions</title>
<?php } ?>
```

Database/testimonials:

testimonial_id | testimonial_name  | Description

1                 testimonial        lorem ipsum
2                 testimonial        lorem ipsum lorem Ipsum

Pagetitle

pagetitle_id  |  page_title

1                testimonial
2                career

Printed the query in modal but not able to display any data.

Need to display the page titles dynamically.

Comment: Something as `return $q->result()[0]->page_title`

Comment: print the `$page_title` by `print_r($page_title)`. You are getting the array instead of value in this variable

Comment: @splash58 got this after adding in modal and tried then 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: models/testimonial_model.php

Line Number: 31
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/testimonial_model.php

Line Number: 31

Comment: @AgamBanga added in controller and checked got this error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: page_title

Filename: controllers/testimonial.php

Line Number: 23

    Careers Testimonial Portfolio Blogs Our Products

Comment: Form codeigniter doc - `result()

This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure` In any case, you should get field value from that array

Comment: try printing in view file instead of controller like this `<title><?php print_r( $page_title); ?></title>`

Comment: @AgamBanga not accepting the if condition it is directly redirecting to else condition only

Comment: Any Suggestions it is not accepting the if statement value directly accepting else statement text only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
function index()
{     

$pageReult = $this->testimonial_model->getpagetitle($this->uri->segment(1));
$data['page_title']=$pageReult->page_title;
$data['mainpage'] = "testimonial";
$this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function getpagetitle($id)
{

    $this->db->select('P.*,T.testimonial_name');        
    $this->db->from('pagetitle AS P');      
    $this->db->join('testimonials AS T','T.testimonial_name=P.page_title','INNER');
    $this->db->where(array('P.page_title'=>$id));       
    $q=$this->db->get();        
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    $output = $q->result();

   return $output[0];
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that result variable is NOT a string, but an array, try using

```
$output = $q->result();
return $output[0];
```

in your model.
so your model would look like:

```
function getpagetitle($id)
{
    $this->db->select('P.*,T.testimonial_name');        
    $this->db->from('pagetitle AS P');
    $this->db->join('testimonials AS T','T.testimonial_name=P.page_title','INNER');     
    $q=$this->db->get();    
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    $output = $q->result();
    return $output[0];
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not accepting the if condition it is taking else condition only

Comment: if its taking else condition,that title will be "<title>Solutions</title>", without any containing the output of the function. Thus it will not produce array error.

Comment: Yes it is taking solutions as a page title but the page title for that page is already inserted into the database.

Comment: ok, so try to use row_array() function, that should work. if it won't, try use instead of 0 index using name of table.

Comment: But the page tilte is there in database then y it is taking elsecondition text if the page title is not there then it should go to else condition

Comment: Not getting you

Comment: EDIT: ok, sorry I missunderstood you.
former:
Im  not talking about else condition. in if($q->num_rows()>0){ /* here */} you do not output correct type of  variable. now you are returning an array according to error. Also this function returns objects, so just to make sure I suggested going with the array function.
try
    $q=$this->db->get();    
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
    $output = $q->result_array()
    return $output[0];
        }

Comment: this only right you said to update in my modal function

Comment: did you sorted it out? can you temporarly add into the modal function var_dump($q->result())?

Comment: array(0) { } it is printing this one

Comment: so something is up with your database querries. but tbh I never debugged codeigniter querries.

Comment: I am not getting you what you are saying